# EXCEL VBA: My macro is creating a 3D dimension array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, for-loop

I have lots of recruitment data that i want to re-arrange, separate and modify using arrays. The data includes all information from 1st stage, 2nd stage and 3rd stage interview for each candidates. The idea is to separate each stage onto their own sheets (e.g. Interview 1, interview 2, interview 3). And then to also create a table that has information from all three stages for each candidate.

Firstly, i have created an array of all the data by declaring the range ("A1:AV10000") as a variant.

Then i have created a loop to loop through this data, and separate each type of event that occurs into their own arrays, using an IF function within the loop. If condition is met, create a new array and add each row that condition is met to an array.

However, i believe my arrays are being made into a 3D array and i am sure how to edit the code so that it remains 2Darray. I understand why the code may be creating 3D array (due to iterating by 1 in the loop), however i am unsure how to write code so it includes all data the row and only iterates as shown below.

e.g. currently it goes (1)(1,1),(1)(1,2) then (2)(1,1),(2)(1,2) then (3)(1,1),(3)(1,2).
I would think it would work if it was (1,1)(1,2) then (2,1)(2,2) then (3,1)(3,2). [Screenshot of array format from local window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caCcx.png)

```
Sub AddProcessStageToArray(SourceWorksheet, RawDataArray, LastrowData, WhatStage, ArrayOutput)

For i = LBound(RawDataArray) To UBound(RawDataArray)
    If RawDataArray(i, 13) = WhatStage And RawDataArray(i, 38) <> "NOK" Then
        o = o + 1

        'Dim ArrayName() As Variant
        ReDim Preserve ArrayOutput(o)
        ArrayOutput(o) = Application.Index(SourceWorksheet.Range("A1:AO" & LastrowData), i, 0)
        
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

The code is being called as shown below.

```
Sub AddITWToArray()

Dim DataWs As Worksheet: Set DataWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")
Dim PoolOfWeekWs As Worksheet: Set PoolOfWeekWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pool of the week")

Dim LastrowData As Long: LastrowData = DataWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim LastColData As Long: LastColData = DataWs.Cells(1 & DataWs.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim LastColDataString As String: LastColDataString = Split(Cells(1, LastColData).Address, "$")(1)

Dim DataRange As Range: Set DataRange = DataWs.Range("A1:" & LastColDataString & LastrowData)
Dim DataArr As Variant: DataArr = DataWs.Range("A1:AO" & LastrowData)

'Loop through Data array, if interview process = PQL, add to table. If interview proces = 1sTITW find postion and add data, if 2ndITW find postion and highlight, if 3rd find postion and highlight

Dim PoolofWeekTableLRow As Long: PoolofWeekTableLRow = PoolOfWeekWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'PoolOfWeekWs.Rows("3:" & PoolofWeekTableLRow).ClearContents

Dim i, o As Long
Dim RowNumberArr As Variant


'Create PQLArray
Dim PQLArray() As Variant
Call AddProcessStageToArray(DataWs, DataArr, LastrowData, "Prequalification", PQLArray)


'Create 1ITWArray
Dim FirstITWArray() As Variant
Call AddProcessStageToArray(DataWs, DataArr, LastrowData, "Candidate Interview 1", FirstITWArray)

'Create 2ITWArray
Dim SecondITWArray() As Variant
Call AddProcessStageToArray(DataWs, DataArr, LastrowData, "Candidate Interview 2+", SecondITWArray)

'Create PPLArray
Dim PPLArray() As Variant
Call AddProcessStageToArray(DataWs, DataArr, LastrowData, "Candidate Interview 2*", PPLArray)
```

Comment: The obtained array is not a 3D array, It is an array of arrays. A, so named, jagged array. In order to return such an array, I think it would be good to transform the `Sub` in a `Function`.  And (even in the existing `Sub`) it would be good to properly declare all the `Sub`/`Function` parameters (`SourceWorksheet As Worksheet, RawDataArray, LastrowData As Long, WhatStage As String`). But where is your real problem? Would you like to read/use/return the jagged array elements?

Comment: Yes. `Application.Index(SourceWorksheet.Range("A1:AO" & LastrowData), i, 0)` returns a 2D array, so you are creating an array of arrays. In these kinds of situations, I usually use a dictionary to collect and organize the data, and then output it as a 2D array after going through all the data. `Redim Preserve` has both overhead, and limitations, when applied to multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @FaneDuru I see. Thank you for point that out i didn't know. What i am trying to do is to return the array elements into a specific sheet for each one. Then using a combination of all arrays created, fill a table with the data combining information from all stages. I am struggling to pass the data from the arrays to the specific sheets

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I understand now, is there a way to add a whole row of elements to an array without creating a jagged/array of array's? Would a dictionary be the only way?

Comment: You could write each individual element. But much simpler to use a Dictionary.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I think a dictionary may be good too, as i need to rearrange the data. Depending on the stage of the interview, the data in column 2 of raw data may be put into the final table at different positions depending on the interview stage. Aka if 1st stage, the date would be in column 2 of final table, but if 2nd stage, it would be in the 6th column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next adapted function, please:

```
Function AddProcessStageToArray(SourceWorksheet As Worksheet, RawDataArray, LastrowData As Long, WhatStage As String) As Variant
Dim ArrayOutput() As Variant, o As Long, i As Long, j As Long

ReDim ArrayOutput(1 To UBound(RawDataArray, 2), 1 To UBound(RawDataArray, 2))
For i = LBound(RawDataArray) To UBound(RawDataArray)
    If RawDataArray(i, 13) = WhatStage And RawDataArray(i, 38) <> "NOK" Then
        o = o + 1
        For j = 1 To UBound(RawDataArray, 2)
            ArrayOutput(j, o) = RawDataArray(i, j)
        Next j
    End If
Next
ReDim Preserve ArrayOutput(1 To UBound(RawDataArray, 2), 1 To o)
AddProcessStageToArray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ArrayOutput)
End Function
```

It can be called in this way:

```
Sub testAddProcessStToArr()
  Dim DataWs As Worksheet, DataArr As Variant, LastrowData As Long
  
  Set DataWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")
    LastrowData = DataWs.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    DataArr = DataWs.Range("A1:AO" & LastrowData)
    Dim PQLArray() As Variant
    PQLArray = AddProcessStageToArray(DataWs, DataArr, LastrowData, "Prequalification")
    Dim NewSheet as Worksheet
    Set NewSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    NewSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(PQLArray), UBound(PQLArray, 2)).Value = PQLArray
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

Please, also try the next approach, involving a preliminary counting of rows respecting the conditions criteria and then use them to fill the final array. The adapted function to be used will be the next:

```
Function AddProcessStageToArr(RawDataArray, arrNo As Variant) As Variant
 Dim ArrayOutput() As Variant, o As Long, i As Long, j As Long

 ReDim ArrayOutput(1 To UBound(arrNo) + 1, 1 To UBound(RawDataArray, 2))
 For i = 0 To UBound(arrNo)
    o = o + 1
    For j = 1 To UBound(RawDataArray, 2)
        ArrayOutput(o, j) = RawDataArray(arrNo(i), j)
    Next j
 Next
 AddProcessStageToArr = ArrayOutput
End Function
```

The above function should be called in the next way:

```
Sub testAddProcessStToArrBis()
  Dim DataWs As Worksheet, DataArr As Variant, LastrowData As Long
  Dim arrNo As Variant, i As Long, k As Long
  
  Set DataWs = ActiveSheet
    LastrowData = DataWs.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    DataArr = DataWs.Range("A1:AO" & LastrowData).Value
    ReDim arrNo(UBound(DataArr))
    For i = 1 To UBound(DataArr)
        If DataArr(i, 13) = "Prequalification" And DataArr(i, 38) <> "NOK" Then
            arrNo(k) = i: k = k + 1
        End If
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve arrNo(k - 1)
    Dim PQLArray() As Variant
    PQLArray = AddProcessStageToArr(DataArr, arrNo)
    Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
    Set NewSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=DataWs)
    NewSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(PQLArray), UBound(PQLArray, 2)).Value = PQLArray
End Sub
```

The same function must be used, but changing "Prequalification" with "Candidate Interview x" and rebuild `arrNo` for each case...

Comment: Thanks @FaneDuru , i have just tested it out! Seems to work all good however i get an application defined error 1004 on thre last line. I wants the array to be managed the opposite way round so 41 in x axis so i switched the o and j counters etc of the Array. Now, some of the array is outputted onto the sheet but stops at line 450 out of 4000.

Comment: @0Marine0: Which "the last line" are you talking about? The `Function` line of the testing `Sub`? Then, you cannot switch the columns with rows in the function! The dimension when which `Resize Preserve` works is **only the last**. Anyhow, after keeping only the array elements keeping data (`o`), the array is transposed, in terms of rows and columns. Can you better explain what you tried and what you need, in fact?

Comment: it was erroring on the transpose, so i took the transpose out and just inputted at the array normally. The problem im trying to solve is i have thousands of lines of data, from all stages of a recruitment process. Now i need to extract each interview stage data and put it into a table. However, the name of the candidate may appear multiple times (1st stage, 2ndstage, 3rdstage). The data will be organised in the final table to show one entry for each candidate, showing the data from all three stages. Thats the final outcome, however i was trying to create separate arrays to start.

Comment: This stage was just asking about arrays, but do you think i should re-write the question to describe the whole outcome. I think a dictionary may be the best way thinking about it.

Comment: @0Marine0 Well, `Application.Transpose` has some limitations (65535 array elements and maximum 255 characters for any element)... I couldn't understand that "lots of recruitment data" may exceed the before mentioned limitations. If the transposition done when the array was built is not problematic, your problem of not showing all its elements comes from the way the code resizes the range to receive all array elements. You must use the last sub code line as: `NewSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(PQLArray, 2), UBound(PQLArray)).Value = PQLArray`. I mean, the rows must be switched with columns.

Comment: @0Marine0: I can show you a Dictionary variant, but I am afraid that you can only keep the rows in the dictionary items **as arrays**, too. And in order to pass them to the range, you must iterate between the Dictionary items. You can do the same using your initial code, but this takes time and consumes Excel resources. I tried supplying a solution to drop the processing result **at once**, which is the fastest way...

Comment: @0Marine0: Another way could be to preliminarily count the occurrences, put the specific rows **number** in an array, then `ReDim` `ArrayOutput` using `Ubound` of it for the rows number and switch the way of its loading. No need of checking again the two conditions, only load the function array with rows of the newly created one. `ArrayOutput(o, j) =` instead of ` ArrayOutput(j, o) =` and no need to `Redim Preserve`.

Comment: I appreaciate your help and advice i am very grateful. I think i may try a dictionary for the final organisation of the table once the process stages are seperated. That way, i can specify each variable of an entry e.g. CanidateID,Name, CanidateID.1stITWDate,CanidateID,Skills, etc.

Comment: The count of row numbers sounds like an ideal way, to count when the candidate appears etc, i shall also try

Comment: @0Marine0: You may try whatever looks more appropriate for you. How will you structure the looping in order to load for each candidate name the correspondent necessary array? Nevermind, I will edit the code and post a variant based my last suggestion, able to deliver the array with rows and columns as they are in the range.

Comment: @0Marine0: Updated the code with the promised version.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. The Array is generate dperfectly, however pasing it to the sheet again erros out at 474 for some weird reason. I guess it has something to do with my data. I will have a look! but again thank you so much!

Comment: @0Marine0: Please, put a break in the testing Sub and see what value does `LastrowData` have. Is it the one you expected? If not something confidential, can you share your workbook to be processed? Using a transfer site. For instance, [here](https://easyupload.io/) it is one easy to be used...